# Automatic redirect when webscrape

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to web scrape this web page and all the "next pages" of this search

[http://g1.globo.com/busca/?q=incerteza+pol%C3%ADtica+economia&cat=a&ss=4da73052cb8296b5&st=G1&species=not%C3%ADcias](http://g1.globo.com/busca/?q=incerteza%20pol%C3%ADtica%20economia&cat=a&ss=4da73052cb8296b5&st=G1&species=not%C3%ADcias)

When I go to page 2 of the search, I correctly excract all the links.

When I go to a page that doesn't exist, the web site redirects to the first page of the search.

[http://g1.globo.com/busca/?q=incerteza+pol%C3%ADtica+economia&cat=a&ss=4da73052cb8296b5&st=G1&species=not%C3%ADcias&page=5000](http://g1.globo.com/busca/?q=incerteza%20pol%C3%ADtica%20economia&cat=a&ss=4da73052cb8296b5&st=G1&species=not%C3%ADcias&page=5000)

Example, if I go to page 2500 I don't get an error, which is what I want, I go back to the first page.

Here is a piece of my code:

```
    try:
        html = urlopen("http://g1.globo.com/busca/?q=economia&cat=a&ss=1885518dc528dd9b&st=G1&species=not%C3%ADcias&page=110") #Search Link
        bsObj = BeautifulSoup(html) #BeautifulSoup's Link
        print(bsObj)
    except OSError:
        print("test")
```

My objective is to Scrape all the available pages and stop the code after that. To do that, firstly, I need to understand what's going on.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you reach the last page, the button gets disabled:

```
 <a data-pagina="2" href="?ss=4da73052cb8296b5&amp;st=G1&amp;q=incerteza+pol%C3%ADtica+economia&amp;cat=a&amp;species=not%C3%ADcias&amp;page=2"
 class="proximo fundo-cor-produto"> próximo</a>
             ^^^^
             # ok

 <a data-pagina="41" href="?ss=4da73052cb8296b5&amp;st=G1&amp;q=incerteza+pol%C3%ADtica+economia&amp;cat=a&amp;species=not%C3%ADcias&amp;page=41"
     class="proximo disabled">próximo</>
             ^^^^
            # no more next pages
```

So just keep looping until then:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from itertools import count

page_count = count(1)
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url.format(next(page_count))).content)
disabled = soup.select_one("#paginador ul li a.proximo.disabled")
print([a["href"] for a in soup.select("div.busca-materia-padrao a")])
print(soup.select_one("a.proximo.disabled"))
while not disabled:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url.format(next(page_count))).content)
    disabled = soup.select_one("#paginador ul li a.proximo.disabled")
    print([a["href"] for a in soup.select("div.busca-materia-padrao a")])
```

If you were using *requests* wanted to check if you had been redirected you could access the  `.history` attribute:

```
In [1]: import requests

In [2]: r = requests.get("http://g1.globo.com/busca/?q=incerteza%20pol%C3%ADtica%20economia&cat=a&ss=4da73052cb8296b5&st=G1&species=not%C3%ADcias&page=5000")

In [3]: print(r.history)
[<Response [301]>]
In [4]:  r.history[0].status_code == 301
Out[4]: True
```

Another way using requests would be to disallow redirects and catch a 301 return code.

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url.format(next(page_count))).content)
print([a["href"] for a in soup.select("div.busca-materia-padrao a")])

while True:
    r = requests.get(url.format(next(page_count)), allow_redirects=False)
    if r.status_code == 301:
        break
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)
    print([a["href"] for a in soup.select("div.busca-materia-padrao a")])
```

Comment: I think your logic is correct, but the while condition doesn't stop the code when it reaches the number of pages.

Comment: @ThalesMarques, yes, I had a typo in my selector, it will work fine now

Comment: The second code still looping after the last page, but the last code works fine. I will work on something like it. Thank you very much!

Answer (score -1):

You could always store a hash of the response from the first page (if it's actual identical) then check to see if the response of each page matches the hash of the first page.

Additionally you could use urllib2

```
import urllib2, urllib
opener = urllib2.build_opener()
urllib2.install_opener(opener)
try: 
    response = urllib2.urlopen('http://g1.globo.com/busca/?q=incerteza+pol%C3%ADtica+economia&cat=a&ss=4da73052cb8296b5&st=G1&species=not%C3%ADcias&page=5000')
    bsObj = BeautifulSoup(response.read()) #BeautifulSoup's Link
    print(bsObj)

except urllib2.HTTPError, err:
    if err.code == 404:
        print "Page not found!"
```